# Text on a path with Pixelmator

Tags: text, path, pixelmator, text-on-path

Is it possible to have text follow a path? Similar to this: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/creating-type-path.html

Comment: I don’t think Pixelmator can do that (yet). Affinity Designer can. Inkscape can. Acorn can (on a circle). As you’ve noted, Illustrator can as well.

Answer (score 0):

For April 2020 this is possible only manually, i.e. there is no such feature in Pixelmator neither in Pixelmator Pro.

This feature will be available in PXMs as it is in the beta development.

The lack of this feature is one of the major PXMs drawbacks making both clones not so different in their limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Pixelmator 1.7 Sequoia added this feature in July 2020. The documentation for that specifically is below, where you can also find other text path features.

https://www.pixelmator.com/support/guide/pixelmator-pro/1289/